# ZED F9P RTK post processing rover + base setup: Which messages to log?

Tags: logging, gps, post-processing, nmea, real-time-kinematic

I am creating a setup with the ZED F9P where I have a rover and base station. Both devices have their own ZED F9P, but cannot communicate with eachother in realtime due to constraints. Because of this I want to do post processing using RTKLIB or similar.

Both devices are connected to their own raspberry pi 4 for logging. No "real" storage space/speed constraints.

Both devices will log the output of the GPS. I have seen various posts explaining how to do rover setup and how to use RTKLIB. My question however is which messages to enable in both devices.

In both the rover and base I have enabled the following messages:

default NMEA
RXM-RAWX
RXM-SFRBX

According to my knowledge and what I read on the internet this would be enough to enable RTK post processing.

Am I right? If not, which messages do I need per device and are there any other things I need to take care of?

Comment: Since there is no real code to this question, I think you might get a better response from https://electronics.stackexchange.com or, since it involves a raspberry pi, https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com remember to tag which pi version and programming laanguage you are using